# Bottom Navigation Need To Clicked 2 Times Before Executing Task

Tags: android, bottomnavigationview

I have a bottom navigation bar, I don't know why, but I need to click it 2 times before executing the task.

This is the xml for bottom navigation

```
<com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:itemBackground="@color/colorPrimary"
    app:itemIconTint="@color/white"
    app:itemTextColor="@color/white"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation_admin" />
```

This is how I call it on activity

```
private void setBottomNavigation() {
    BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView = findViewById(R.id.bottom_navigation_view);
    bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemReselectedListener(new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemReselectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onNavigationItemReselected(@NonNull MenuItem menuItem) {
            switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.navigation_override :
                    fragment = new OverrideFragment();
                    fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_layout, fragment).commit();
                    break;
                case R.id.navigation_user:
                    fragment = new UserListFragment();
                    fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_layout, fragment).commit();
                    break;
                case R.id.navigation_log_out:
                    CustomDialog customDialog = new CustomDialog(AdminBoardActivity.this);
                    customDialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
                    customDialog.show();
                    break;
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You use

**bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemReselectedListener** instead of
`bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener`

not Reselected only Selected ;)

Answer (score 0):

You are setting a reselect listener but you need to set onitem select listener.
replace

```
 bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemReselectedListener()
```

with

```
BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener()
```

Answer (score 0):

you are using  setOnNavigationItemReselectedListener

use this
    `setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener`